# How to get arguments object in scalajs

Tags: scala.js

In JS, I can access the function arguments through the `arguments` object.

I want to do the same thing somehow in ScalaJS, because I want to do some logging for functions and what parameters they got.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please update your question with a snippet of what you are trying to do. The question in its current form is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm -- interesting question. I honestly don't know if there is a way to access `arguments` per se. I would probably address the desire for logging the function arguments by using the [sourcecode library](https://index.scala-lang.org/lihaoyi/sourcecode/sourcecode?target=_sjs0.6_2.12), which is designed for that sort of thing, but I'll admit that I haven't tried that from Scala.js yet...

Comment: Is it not possible to emit pure js somehow from the base scalajs? I'd rather not introduce additional libs.

Comment: Sourcecode will perfectly work on Scala.js (and only emit "pure" JS).

Comment: Yeah, it really sounds like sourcecode is probably the best way to do what's being looked for here...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access the `arguments` object in Scala.js. However, you can export a method with varargs and it will work as expected in JavaScript:

```
object Logger {
  @JSExportTopLevel("log")
  def log(xs: js.Any*): Unit = {
    xs.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

This defines and exports `log` to the top level scope. In the JavaScript code, you can now call:

```
log(1, {}, {a: 1}, "foo");
```

Comment: Thanks, that means I'd need to pass along every argument every time. That's a lot less convenient than just passing the arguments object.

Comment: @romeozor I do not understand what you mean. In the above snippet, `xs` basically is the same thing as the `arguments` object. You can pass that one around.

Comment: @gzm0 in my Scala code, I want to drop in some logging calls, which is also Scala code, and then compile it to JS. `arguments` in JS gives me access to all function parameters. The problem is not the logging, it's the passing parameters. I could have a function with 1, argument, another with 3, and I would need to call `log()` with those same parameters. However, if I had access to `arguments`, I could just pass that `log(arguments)`.

Comment: @romeozor I still do not understand what you are actually trying to do, that is not covered by the above answer. Could you please edit your question with a snippet showing what you would do in JS? That would give us an unambiguous understanding of what you're asking.

Comment: @sjrd what he wants to do is trace all the function calls. Essentially in every function he wants to add a call `trace("functionName", arguments)` so you get a "call-log". I guess in Scala that's only possible using implicit or macro metaprogramming.

Answer (score 1):

As @justin-du-coeur suggested, you can use [sourcecode](https://index.scala-lang.org/lihaoyi/sourcecode/sourcecode?target=_sjs0.6_2.12) for this. For example:

```
object Test extends js.JSApp {
  def main(): Unit = {
    a(1, "a")
    b()
    c("foo", "bar", "baz")
  }

  def trace()(implicit name: sourcecode.Name, args: sourcecode.Args): Unit = {
    def makeArgList(as: Seq[sourcecode.Text[_]]): String =
      as.map(a => f"${a.source} = ${a.value}").mkString("(", ", ", ")")

    val argStr = args.value.map(makeArgList).mkString("")
    println(f"${name.value}$argStr")
  }

  def a(arg1: Int, arg2: String): Unit = {
    trace()
  }

  def b(): Unit = {
    trace()
  }

  def c(x: String*): Unit = {
    trace()
  }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
[info] Running Test
a(arg1 = 1, arg2 = a)
b()
c(x = WrappedArray(foo, bar, baz))
```

As you can see, `trace` can capture everything it needs from the context, so the result is even more boilerplate free than any JS solution I can think of.